# How to add Caption to a flow chart?

Tags: captions

Is there a simple way that  I can add caption to the flow chart ?

```
\caption{A simple table}
```

is not working 
Thanks

Comment: Could you provide a MWE to your question? Also note, that you are missing the '}' and that '%' interprets all following characters on this line as a comment.

Comment: @Richard thanks I found the answer and I added the code with the result

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer is to write caption line just after the begin figure here is my working example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\graphicspath{ {Images/} }
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{figure}
\caption{An example graph}

\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30]

\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=3cm, draw=black, fill=orange!30]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\tikzstyle{mytext} = [text width=0.5cm,color= red,text centered]

%\begin{frame}
\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth,height=15 cm,keepaspectratio}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]

\node (start) [startstop] {Start};
\node (in1) [io, below of=start] {Enter Command };
\draw [arrow] (start) -- (in1);
\node (send) [process, below of=in1] {send Command};
\draw [arrow] (in1) -- (send);
\node (receive) [process, below of=send] {Receive  Response};
\draw [arrow] (send) -- (receive);
\node (done) [decision, below of=receive, yshift= -1.0cm] {All bytes received ?};
\draw [arrow] (receive) -- (done);
\draw [arrow] (done)-|   ([xshift=1.0cm]  done.east) |-   (receive) ;
\node[mytext, below left of= done,xshift= 3.6cm,yshift= 1.6cm] (doneno) {No}; 
%\node[text, below left of= done,xshift= 1.8cm,yshift= 0.8cm] (doneyes) {yes};
\node (okok) [decision, below of=done, yshift= -2.5cm] {Every thing is O.K.? };
\draw [arrow] (done) -- node[anchor=south,xshift= .3cm, yshift= -.2cm] {\color[rgb]{1,0,0} yes} (okok);
% Connect okok yes to enter command 
%\draw [arrow] (okok)-|   ([xshift=1.5cm]  okok.east) |-   (in1) ;



%print the response okok=yes
\node[mytext, below left of=okok,xshift= 3.6cm,yshift= 1.6cm] (okokyes) {Yes}; 
\node (printokyes) [process, right of=receive,xshift=3cm] {Print the response };
\draw [arrow] (okok)-|   ([xshift=3cm]  okok.east) --   (printokyes) ;
\draw [arrow] (printokyes)|-  (in1);

%print the response okok=no
\node[mytext, below right of=okok,xshift= -3.6cm,yshift= 1.6cm] (okokyes) {No}; 
\node (printokno) [process, left of=receive,xshift=-3cm] {Print "error" + the response(error number) };
\draw [arrow] (okok)-|   (  okok.west) -|   (printokno) ;
\draw [arrow] (printokno)|-  (in1);
%\draw [arrow] (done) -- {yes}(okok);
***% when I was writing caption here it was the error*** 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}


\end{figure}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Yup, \caption has to be inside a float environment, either before or after the picture/tabular/whatever.  OTOH, \captionof can be used almost anywhere.

Comment: Usually figure captions go at the bottom of the figure

Answer (score 0):

wrap the whole flow chart inside \begin{figure} element and add[H] position specifier along with it. It looks something like:

\begin{figure}[H]
...
...
...
\caption{caption here}
\label{label here}
\end{figure}

here the position specifier [H] stands for here and it overrides all the inbuilt positioning rules and guidelines.

it positions the flow chart wherever the location of the code for the corresponding figure is inside the latex file.